# Changing the package from the REPL in SLIME - is it broken?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

I just recently started experiment with SLIME, and found a problem that makes me unsure whether it is something I am doing wrong or if the current snapshot of SLIME is broken.

The problem:  trying to change the package (using , !p) always throws an error, regardless of which backend is used.

The error from SBCL looks like this:

> The value #("FOO" 0 3 (SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::FACE NIL)) is not of type (OR (VECTOR CHARACTER) (VECTOR NIL) BASE-STRING SYMBOL CHARACTER PACKAGE).
>   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

CLISP and CCL throw the same error, though worded slightly differently.

I am running on Windows, but the same thing happens when I try it on Linux.  I suspect that either there is something I am neglecting to do in my .emacs file, or there is a glitch in the current version of SLIME.  I just started using SLIME yesterday, so I have no past experiences to compare it to.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you just issue the command (in-package ...)?

Comment: Yes, this does work correctly.   I am just wondering why the !p way of doing it causes the error...

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. What version of slime is it? You could try grabbing the latest from source and see if that helps.

Comment: It is the latest from CVS (it says "; SLIME 2009-04-21" when the REPL first opens).  Just to be sure, I did a CVS update after you asked this and nothing has changed.

Comment: What are you typing as the package name, is it literally foo, or "foo", or 'foo?

In my case just foo.

Comment: Literally FOO, as it appears in the completion list for the !p command.

Comment: I grabbed the latest again and it still works. This is on windows with lispworks. 

Have you tried deleting any fas/fasl files that may be stale?